# What Database Information Applies to What Connection String Attributes

Tags: sql-server, iis, web-config, connection-string

I am attempting to deploy my ASP .NET MVC 4.5 website to my server. I have all the Database details and my connection string written.

But I am unsure if my Connection String attributes are correct and if I have any the wrong way around. I am especially confused whether `Data Source` represents the database name or instance and whether `Initial Catalog` is my server or something else?

Given my database information below, is my connection string correct? I am uploading my files to my server now so I haven't had a chance to test it yet.

> DB Server: mssql.mywebsite.com
>   DB Instance: .\MSSQLSERVER2014
>   DB Name: DB_mydatabase
>   DB User: myUserName
>   DB Password: myPassword

```
<add name="MyName"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER2014;
                       AttachDbFileName=DB_mydatabase;
                       Initial Catalog=mssql.mywebsite.com;
                       User ID=myUserName;
                       Password=myPassword;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Your connection string looks suspect but we need to know more about your environment to help more, specifically if this is SQL Express or a higher edition.  Please include the results of `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')` in your question.

Comment: Datasource is the server (and instance name), initial catalog is the database name.